# Is there a way to adapt datatable width with sidebar width in shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, shinydashboard, dt

I have the shiny dashboard below and as you see I want to display a datatable inside sidebar but the issue is that the table is much wider. Can I make the table fit in exactly in the sidebar without  increasing sidbar width?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Table" , tabname = "my_table", icon = icon("table"),DT::dataTableOutput("example_table")
                   ),
          menuItem("Next Widget", tabName = "Other"))),

      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          tabItem(tabName = "subMenu", #my_table",
                  fluidRow(
                  )),
          tabItem(tabName = "Other",
                  h2("Other tab")
          )
        )))
    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$example_table <- DT::renderDataTable(head(mtcars))
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way is to enable horizontal scrolling for your `DT`. Then the table will fit the container but be scrollable:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Table" , tabname = "my_table", icon = icon("table"),DT::dataTableOutput("example_table")
      ),
      menuItem("Next Widget", tabName = "Other"))),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "subMenu", #my_table",
              fluidRow(
              )),
      tabItem(tabName = "Other",
              h2("Other tab")
      )
    )))
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$example_table <- DT::renderDataTable(head(mtcars), options = list(scrollX=TRUE))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]